# What happens if you ride a bike on to a moving sidewalk?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, inertial-frames, relative-motion

If a person were to riding a bicycle on normal ground then ride onto a conveyer moving in the forward direction of the bicycle (like a moving sidewalk in an airport), would the bike slow down or speed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to a stationary observer, you and the bike would speed up once going on the conveyor belt. Essentially, biking on a convey belt merely adds to your velocity relative to that stationary observer.

However, a distinction should be made that the conveyor belt is supplying kinetic energy to you and your bike; you aren't yourself supplying more energy to move the bike to speed it up.

Comment: "The bike would not slow down nor speed up. Relative to a stationary observer, however, you and the bike would speed up..." Huh?  Your initial sentence doesn't really make sense.  In that first sentence, the bike doesn't speed up or slow down _relative to what_?  As it stands right now your first two sentences immediately contradict each other, since your first sentence doesn't give any reference to what it doesn't slow down or speed up relative to.

Comment: I  mean to say the bike would not slow down nor speed up *itself*, meaning the rate at which you pedal isn't changing. You aren't supplying more energy to the bike to increase your speed. I'll edit it for clarity.

Comment: I still don't see the real point of that first sentence, it confuses it more than anything; especially since the question doesn't mention anything about pedal speed; it only asks if the bike speeds up or slows down.  It might be worth mentioning that the speed it gains doesn't come from the person; but I don't like the way you lead with that.  It's not that important in the answer.

Comment: @JMac Fair enough. I neglected to mention the pedalling bit now.